# redirect loop eror ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on .net Umbraco site

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have following rule written in web.config , which was working fine when the site was on Dedicated server and now we have moved the site to shared hosting.
(As the site is in umbraco)

```
<rule name="Redirect www.SiteName.com to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.SiteName.com$" negate="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.siteName.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

As we need to move any request on `www.siteName.com` to `https://`

but when I activate above code on site I am start getting following error message on

[image]

I have also check the site re-direction request on http://redirectdetective.com/
As I is also showing loop of https

[image]

As I have also got conformation from hosting provider that they have not set any re-direction

Answer (score -1):

Finally I have to write re-direction rule in .Js of master page. To avoid redirection loop

As following is the code which I have write in JS.

```
<script language="javascript">
    if (document.location.protocol != "https:")
    {
      document.location.href = "https://www.siteName.com" + document.location.pathname;
    };
</script>
```

Kindly share if there is any better solution.